# VBA Excel - save as word document not working

Tags: vba, excel

Somebody please help me before my laptop goes sailing out the window. I have created an Excel userform that, after everything is entered, copies text from one cell on the worksheet and pastes it into a new Word document. It works beautifully, and the Word document opens like it's supposed to and pastes the contents of the cell into it. I could manually save the open Word document at that point, but I want the document to save with a specific filename and into a specific folder, then close Word completely. The SaveAs didn't work for me; I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my first post btw - was hoping that I would find my answer by searching, but after hours of searching and trying different things, I gave in and posted. I apologize in advance if I break any question-asking etiquette rules!

The following code is for a button click on my userform, snipped right after I copy the cell I want to paste into Word. 
Edit: I changed my original question to reflect that I tried the SaveAs2 fix suggested. I'm now getting the error "Invalid or unqualified reference". Help?

```
'copy to word
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim objDoc As New Word.Document

'Copy the range I want to paste in new Word document
Range("M47").Copy

'Paste into the new Word document
With objWord
    .Documents.Add
    .Selection.Paste
    .Visible = True
End With

'****************WORKS FINE UP UNTIL THIS POINT.

'The document opens with the text I want in it.

'Creating the special filename
Dim strFilename     As String
Dim rngRange        As Range

'Cell in Excel Worksheet from where filename is to be picked (patient date    of birth)
Set rngRange = Worksheets("Scores").Range("D95")

'Create File name with DOB, 'PAI', & today's date
strFilename = rngRange.Value & "PAI" & Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy")

 .SaveAs2 Filename:=("C:\Users\Mary Anne\Google Drive\") & strFilename, _
FileFormat:=16

End Sub
```

Comment: Debugger stops, what does it *tell you*?  What is the line that it stops on? You didn't include any of that information, which we would need to help troubleshoot...

Comment: What sort of value is in `rngRange` cell?  Is it just a date value? Or is it a full file path?

Comment: Please post the code that saves the word document, kind of hard to help you without seeing that. also post the value held in D95 or verify that is doesnt contain / \ : * ? " < > | characters

Comment: Use the `SaveAs2` method of the `objDoc` document with the parameter 1 as the full path of the file (`"C:\Users\..." & strFileName`) and the constant `16` as second parameter, which means the standard `docx` extension.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. I edited the original question to reflect that I tried the SaveAs2 fix, but apparently I have no idea what I'm doing because it didn't work and gave me an error 'invalid or unqualified reference'. What did I do wrong? Oh, the value in rngRange is a date value, not a file path. It works fine in another userform that I save as a .pdf file.

Comment: Also, the value of D95 in the filename is just 6 digits with no other characters from a cell formatted as "general". Like I said, strFilename works fine on another userform that I save as a .pdf, but apparently saving as a word document is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the object you are using the method onto:

```
objDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Users\Mary Anne\Google Drive\" & strFilename, 16
```

Find more about the `SaveAs2` method in the [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx)

What you're doing wrong, in fact, is calling the method on no object:

```
.SaveAs2
```

I bet my hat you have copied this line of code from a `With` block like the following, so I will explain you what it means :) :

```
With objDoc '<-- "with the objDoc", we will...
'...        '<-- "do many stuffs, among them we will also..."
.SaveAs2    '<-- "save the objDoc as SaveAs2"
'...
End With
```

The `.SaveAs2` means there's an object previously called in a `With` block, it cannot stand alone or you will get a compile error.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. I think I understand what you mean; however, I don't know how to modify my code to make it work. What should I add to my code to get it to work?

Comment: Okay, so I just added objDoc. onto my original SaveAs2 line, but now it saves a blank Word document with my strFilename (closing it) and pastes my cell onto another Document1 and leaves it open. So it's basically creating two Word documents: one with my cell pasted onto it and the other with the filename I specified with nothing in it. I'm missing something big time here.

Comment: @MaryAnne this is because `objDoc` is an empty Word document, you don't assign it as the one you add to your Word application. In your 5th line of code, replace `.Documents.Add` with `Set objDoc = .Documents.Add`: this will add your new document to the application and at the same time setting `objDoc` as the reference to it, so avoiding the problem you're talking about now.